# how to handle javascript that only runs on certain pages when bundled together

Tags: javascript, jquery

When working on small client sites, I often end up working with a main.js file that includes a bunch of jQuery plugins and small toggle functionality. Some of these code snippets are only relevant on certain pages, but ends up bundled together in one main.min.js file.

My question is, how do people write the individual code snippets in order to only execute that code when the correct page is being rendered?

Here's an example: Let's say I have a page with a search input field. This input is hooked up with [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in order to show search suggestions as the user types. the code in main.js could look something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 'some value',
        data: 'some data'
    },
    {...}
]
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: data,
    lookupLimit: 10,
    minChars: 3,
});
```

This code is only useful on the template that has that input field, but as main.js contains a bunch of other smaller bits like this that are useful globally and on other pages, the whole file is loaded on every pageview. What strategy should I use to only execute that piece of code when the page needs it?

I though of a few ways my self:

- Check if the DOM-element (in this case #autocomplete) exists.
- Check if the URL is == '/page-with-autocomplete'.
- Use a class on , and check for that class i n order to run the script.
- Other ideas? Any standard way to do this sort of thing? Anything considered a "best practice"?

Comment: They probably just break it up - usually it's just main.js and you use 100% unique ids so only certain things run when the id is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick your JS in an if block and check for the unique DOM element on the page you want the script to run. 
Although you can't just do:

```
if ( $('#my-el') ) {}
```

You have to check if the element has a length, like:

```
if ( $('#my-el').length ) {}
```